# How can I emulate the paths to my Django project on my dev environment to be the same as production? 

Tags: django, django-settings

I need to setup a Django dev environment.

I did a `git clone`  and pulled all the django project files from production on my local machine (a [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) enabled VM).

The problem is that my local machine has a different path to the project than my production ( and I can't change that) so it's having problems finding modules stated under INSTALLED_APPS on my local machine.

For example on the production my project is on the `/myproject` folder while on my local machine is under `/vagrant/web/myproject`.

On the production I'm accessing my app modules like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( 'myproject.myapp')
```

Also within the Django apps I'm accessing various app modules like this:

```
from myproject.myapp.models import *
```

What do I need to do to emulate production paths to my modules on my dev box so I don't have to change the paths to the modules on my local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing project-relative imports, all you need to do is ensure that the path directly above your project is on the `PYTHONPATH`.

You need only issue the following at the command line:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/vagrant/web'
```

If you're using virtualenv, you can add that line to your environment's bin/activate file.

Comment: I had to go and add a python path to the project on the production env. so as krs suggested not to use hard-coded paths. Then I had to do the same on my dev env.

Answer (score 2):

The path to your application directory should not matter there as long as you dont have hard-coded paths in settings.py, what web server are you using?

Comment: I'm using NGINX with FASTCGI.

Comment: This was a good advice of not having hard-coded paths. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py:

```
import os
prj_root = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

And `prj_root` will be path to your root project folder